# Return JSON value from jQuery Ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to loop through a json object and output the value but the value keeps returning as "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

JSON

```
{"AssetGUID":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","AwayForRepair":false}
```

JavaScript

```
function runSync() {
    var url = "http://207.230.229.209/tag/assettags.json";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: successHandlerRunSync,
        error: errorHandlerRunSync,
        dataType: "json",
        jsonpCallback: 'parseJSON' // specify the callback name if you're hard-coding it
    });
    $('#jsonMsg').html('Running...');
    $('#jsonRslt').html(' ');
}

function successHandlerRunSync(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
    $('#jsonMsg').html("RunSync Success <br>status: " + textStatus);
    $('#jsonRslt').html(dataJSON);

    var content = '';
    var dataj = $.parseJSON(data);

    $.each(dataj, function(i, post) {
    content += '<li>' + post.AssetGUID + '</li>';
    content += '<li>' + post.AwayForRepair+ '</li>';
    });

    $(content).appendTo("#addJSON");

    console.log("RunSync Success");
    console.log(data);
    console.log(dataJSON);
    console.log(textStatus);
}
```

Output

```
AssetGuid : undefined
AwayForRepair : undefined
```

Comment: That's not what the `jsonpCallback` parameter is for.  That should be the name of the callback function that the JSON is wrapped in.  It's not a "filter" function or anything.  It's what jQuery uses as your "success" param for JSONP.

Comment: how abt `dataj.AssetGUID` and `dataj.AwayForRepair`

Comment: Do you own `207.230.229.209`?  Is your code running on that same server?  JSONP is something that the ***server*** needs to support.  It doesn't magically let you get arbitrary JSON files.  Are you sure this service even supports JSONP (or CORS)?

Comment: Code runs on the same server and it supports jsonp.

Comment: If the code runs on the same server, then you don't need JSONP.  JSONP is only for cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your code runs on the same server, so get rid of the `jsonpCallback` parameter.  You're not using JSONP here, it's only for cross-domain requests.

```
var url = "http://207.230.229.209/tag/assettags.json";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: successHandlerRunSync,
    error: errorHandlerRunSync,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

And then, in your callback, the JSON will *already* be parsed for you, no need to call `$.parseJSON`.

```
function successHandlerRunSync(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    var content = '';

    $.each(data, function(i, post) {
        content += '<li>' + post.AssetGUID + '</li>';
        content += '<li>' + post.AwayForRepair+ '</li>';
    });

    $(content).appendTo("#addJSON");
}
```